# Wallet error ErrorFile=.... /testnet3/wallets/db.log

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, nodes

I want to use two deamon for sync mainnet and testnet.

I Run `$ bitcoind` for mainnet without problem
After I run `$ bitcoind -testnet` But I get this error

```
BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/db.log
```

When I run the testnet, bitcoind creates testnet3 folder

I'm using bitcoin 0.17.1

My conf

```
# /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

# remove the following line to enable Bitcoin mainnet
# testnet=1

# Bitcoind options
server=1
daemon=1

# Connection settings
rpcuser=xxxxxxxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxxx

onlynet=ipv4
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333

# Raspberry Pi optimizations
dbcache=100
maxorphantx=10
maxmempool=50
maxconnections=40
maxuploadtarget=5000
```